# Containers and iterators (multiple choice)

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

STL iterators are used with container classes and are conceptually similar to pointers to speciﬁc elements stored in the container.

One of the statements below is true. Which one?

1. An iterator typically holds an address (pointer), and operator++ applied to the iterator always increases that address.
2. When iterator `it` goes out of scope in a program, `it` gets destructed, which automatically invokes `delete it`;.
3. For a valid STL container myC, when the expression myC.end()-myC.begin() is well-deﬁned, it returns the same value as myC.size().
4. When a container goes out of scope, all iterators that point to it are automatically modiﬁed.
5. For a valid STL container myC, the iterator returned by myC.end() refers to the last valid element in myC.

Apparently the solution is 3. but I don't understand why.  Can someone elaborate on why this is the case, and possibly show why the others are false as well?

Comment: Do you understand any of the five?

Comment: Can you explain what actually happens in each instance then?  What does "well-defined" mean in 3.?

Comment: @BobJohn it means the iterators support arithmetic subtraction, which is possible for one class of iterators, [RandomAccessIterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Think of the requirements of the addresses of items in a linked-list (`list`). They don't need to be sequential in memory.
2. `delete` is something that's manually done on pointers, it wouldn't happen automatically (even if the pointer goes out of scope) (unless done in some API). Iterators are (generally) classes, so `delete` would not even apply. The iterator would get destructed though.

   You can also probably classify a pointer as an iterator. But `delete` will still not be called automatically.
3. Note that [this only applies to random access iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/). You can calculate the number of items in a container as follows:

   ```
   int count = 0;
   for (iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it, ++count) { }
   ```

   so you increment `begin()` `count` times to get to `end()`,
   so `begin() + count = end()`,
   so `end() - begin() = count`, and `count = size()`,
   so `end() - begin() = size()`
4. This is not the way C++ works. Although there are design patterns to achieve this behaviour, usually when modifying a class, it's your responsibility to ensure any dependent classes are updated if invalidated. When you'd try to use an iterator of a container that went out of scope, this would result in undefined behaviour.
5. `end()` is past the last element, probably with something like this in mind: (I'm sure among other reasons)

   ```
   for (iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it)
   ```

Comment: For #3, "when the expression myC.end()-myC.begin() is well-deﬁned" would imply that they're random access iterators. So it is indeed true.

Comment: By your own list, if the expression `myC.end()-myC.begin()` is *well-defined* as the question states it is, then it must be (and can only be) a RandomAccessIterator, at which point #3 is **true**, not false.

Comment: 2 is wrong. Pointers that point to array elements are iterators too.